# Usar AndroidStudio en procesador AMD para ejecutar y depurar una app

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas noches.

El día de hoy he instalado Android Studio y estoy probando mi primera app. He seguido los pasos de un tutorial, y todo marcha bien. Sin embargo al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación para depurarla Android Studio me lanza el error de que el emulador no puede ser ejecutado debido a que no tengo VT Virtualization Tecnology habilitado, presente unicamente en los procesadores Intel.

Hay alguna manera de ejecutar mi app en mi pc con AMD.? FX 6300 Soporta virtualización.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si tienes dispositivos en Android usalos para probar las aplicaciones/juegos, tendrás una perspectiva más audaz de cómo anda tu código

Comment: Yo te sugiero que uses un emulador externo como https://www.genymotion.com/ eh sabido de mucha gente que ha configurado el emulador de Android Studio para AMD pero les va muy lento.

Comment: Buenas noches, he terminado usando mi Tablet para las pruebas, en Google explican como configurarlo. Y me va bien 

Comment: Bueno como dice el amigo @EduardoVelazquez debería de irte bien, y lo otro como ser un procesador ADM, android studio no habilita como tu dices el VT, porque en Intel existe algo que se llama HAXM, que eso sirve para acelerar el emulador, en muchas otras comunidades dicen que sino tienes, eso eres un loco al tratar de emular sin eso. Ya que te va super lento y android consume muchos recursos. Pero también te consejo compilar tus programas con un dispositivo android que va muy bien y no tendras incovenientes.
Saludos.

Comment: yo he solucionado siguiendo las instrucciones de este video,
https://youtu.be/57vZtl5l9hk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en muchos casos la virtualizacion viene desactivada por fabrica, solo hay que activarla en tu procesador.

Enciende la laptop
presiona f2 o f1 para entrar a la bios
busca un menu de features o CPU
debe de tener una opcion VT-Virtualization 
Ponlo en ENABLE o ACTIVAR
Presionas F10 o guardar cambios y salir
Y ya deberias poder virtualizar tu SO Android

Recomendacion; puedes ejecutar tu aplicacion en tu celular si tienes telefono android, solo tienes que activar la depuracion usb o modo desarrollador. Es diferente en cada telefono, puedes buscarlo en google. Te ahorrara mucho tiempo de ejecucion en la maquina virtual de android studio.

Saludos!

Comment: Ya lo he intentado tengo activa la virtualización AMD-V sin embargo en la documentación oficial dice que sólo funciona con Intel-VT. Quisiera saber como hacer la depuración con AMD.

Comment: @MiguelAvendaño si tienes un dispositivo android, úsalo, y te evitas de momento algun trabajo tortuoso, mientras depuras con el dispositivo, vas buscando la solución a tu equipo

Comment: Hola amigos, ya he podido probar muchas opciones pero definitivamente hice lo que aconsejan de usar un dispositivo Android y va bien, aunque en ocasiones genera uno que otro lío pero nada que no se pueda solucionar... Gracias a todos.